# docker info command doesn't show anything in ec2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, devops, amazon-ecs

I have installed docker using sudo yum install -y docker and started the docker service by running the following commands. Initially, it worked and I was able to run docker containers. Now the docker daemon is working but wen I run docker commands like docker ps, docker info..etc. It's not showing anything on stdout.

I have uninstalled the docker version using sudo yum remove docker and removed all the files manually and installed the new one but still it's the same issue.

Here is the link that I have followed to install docker in EC2 instance.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/set-up-a-build-pipeline-with-jenkins-and-amazon-ecs/

Docker version
 1.12.6, build 7392c3b/1.12.6

uname -a
Linux ip adress 4.4.41-36.55.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 18 01:03:26 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I was not able to figure out what went wrong? Could you please help me in debug this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from what you said and going through the link you mentioned, you have given the docker command capabilities to the user jenkins, which you have done using :

```
usermod -a -G docker jenkins
```

So in order to run docker related command you should login as the user Jenkins. You can use the following command to login as the user jenkins.

```
sudo -su jenkins
```

From there you should be able to run the docker commands as expected. 
PS - Follow the steps again to install docker.

Hope this help.